# PHP User Login and own profile page script

Tags: php

I am looking for a script or a fast way of putting together a site where the user can d the following:

**1. Register
2. Login
3. Have own user dashboard ...ie: Name, Surname, etc...**

Security is not important at this point, just a quick way of putting this together.

All the user needs to do once registered is login and be able to edit / Add / Delete a few simple details.

Does anyone know of a simple script to do this quick...Either free or paid...must be simple though.

Comment: What have you looked at so far?

Comment: I've been googling but found nothing that's very simple and fast to get together. This is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Then you are either lying or wasn't looking good enough. You want to tell us that you haven't discovered any CMS through the proccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of the available CMS applications out there: drupal, wordpress or the like.

They work, offer endless possibilities and they are free (as in speech).

ownCloud might also be worth considering. When no apps are activated it offers little more than an account.

Comment: Wordpress, Drupal etc offers this but lots more, I just need something very simple, straight to the point.

Comment: I'd say you won't find anything finished that does not offer any additional features. Simply because the account adminsitration itself makes little sense.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just code one yourself? PHPacademy has 2 nice tutorials:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE134D877783367C7 (nice, safe)

Another tutorial (very unsafe, very ugly, only *login* (can be built on)) is here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oSCuEtxRK8 (part 1)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7ae_cZahPs (part 2)